# Application crashes after converting code to (G+H). GMS and HMS support

Tags: android, google-maps, huawei-mobile-services, supportmapfragment

I have converted the code with the help of HMS toolkit to support both GMS and HMS. but after the conversion, it crashes and throws exception.

> Process: com.example.android.wander.huawei, PID: 10649
> java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.example.android.wander.huawei.MapsActivity: void com.example.android.wander.huawei.MapsActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) failed to verify: void com.example.android.wander.huawei.MapsActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle): [0x11] 'this' argument 'Reference: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager' not instance of 'Reference: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager' (declaration of 'com.example.android.wander.huawei.MapsActivity' appears in /data/app/~~M8blTtc1ehsAE-ySiPYUtQ==/com.example.android.wander.huawei-0H3LEYclNRMAw9Pq-MrWww==/base.apk)
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
> at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
> at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

after i removed the line from application class.

```
XLoader.init(this);
```

this exception went away and then

```
SupportMapFragment.newInstance()
```

throws runtimeexception 'stub'

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Map Kit Manual Conversion Guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/map-conversion-0000001050062227#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050062227__section7696125884610) and follow the guide step by step. After the Add HMS API conversion is complete, you can configure the ClassLoader (simple, only resource import and configuration file modification are required) or manually write code (complex, heavy manual conversion workload) to implement the compatibility of Google APIs and HMS for **activity** displayed in **fragment**.

Currently, the ClassLoader solution does not support the plug-in or hot fix framework in projects, and does not support ClassLoader customization. If your app has such requirements, manually write the code.

---

- [Configuring the ClassLoader](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/map-conversion-0000001050062227#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050062227__section8909144184813)

When the Add HMS API policy is used, the XClassLoader solution is provided to solve the problem that some APIs cannot be converted in combination mode. This solution is used to reduce the workload of manually modifying resources. In this mode, the tool generates a built-in xmsaux module in the xmsadapter module. The xmsaux module contains the xg, xh, and xapi modules and the XClassLoader code.

1. Modify the project-related configuration files.

a. If **Generate code for creating app dependent only on GMS SDK** is selected and the single **xmsg** flavor variant is enabled, modify the reference configuration in the project-level **settings.gradle** file as follows:

```
include ':xmsadapter:xmsaux', 'xmsadapter:xmsaux:xg', 'xmsadapter:xmsaux:xapi'
```

If **Generate code for creating app dependent only on HMS SDK** is selected and the single **xmsh** flavor variant is enabled, modify the reference configuration in the project-level **settings.gradle** file as follows:

```
include ':xmsadapter:xmsaux', 'xmsadapter:xmsaux:xh', 'xmsadapter:xmsaux:xapi'
```

If any of the preceding modes is selected and the single **xmsgh** flavor variant is enabled, modify the reference configuration in the project-level **settings.gradle** file as follows:

```
include ':xmsadapter:xmsaux', 'xmsadapter:xmsaux:xg', 'xmsadapter:xmsaux:xh', 'xmsadapter:xmsaux:xapi'
```

b. In the **dependencies {}** section of the project-level **build.gradle** file, set the Gradle plug-in version to 3.5.0 or later.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}
```

c. In the project-level **gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** file, set the Gradle version to 5.4.1 or later.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

d. For a multi-module project, add the following configuration to the **gradle.properties** file in the project-level directory:

```
android.enableD8=false
android.enableD8.desugaring=false
```

2. Call the **init** method at the program entry to initialize the program.
   a. Implement a program entry class that inherits **android.app.Application** in the app and override the **onCreate** method in the class.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        GlobalEnvSetting.init(this,null);
        XLoader.init(this);
    }
}
```

b. Modify the **application name** attribute in the app-level **src/main/AndroidManifest.xml** file and add the new **application** subclass in the first entry.

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
</application>
```

3. Handle the exception.

---

- [Manually Writing Code](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/map-conversion-0000001050062227#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050062227__section871416020497)

1. Modify the layout resource files. In the Add HMS API scenario, Google APIs and HMS need to use independent layout resource files. The **class** paths in the resource files are different. Each layout resource file must be in duplicate, one for HMS and the other for Google APIs. The files are used together with the code for compatible redirection.
2. Modify the code.
   If **Fragment** is used, you can use **if-else** in the **onCreate()** method of **activity** to make a copy of the code compatible with both HMS and Google APIs.

Comment: followed the given instruction but it does not remove the error.

Comment: @Tahaalam Could you plz provide screenshots of **build.gradle**, **setting.gradle**, and **Build Variants**?